# Encapsular o arquivo de properties em uma classe é uma boa prática?

Tags: java

Em outras linguagens como Python é possível realizar lógica de programação nos arquivos de configuração e em Java isso não é permitido por ser uma linguagem compilada.

Resolvi encapsular as configurações do arquivo `.properties` em um objeto Java, com isso tenho a vantagem de poder validar as informações do arquivo, gerar lógica de programação e até utilizar o autocomplete do Eclipse porém tenho a desvantagem de não poder criar propriedades dinamicamente, por isso tenho a dúvida se isso é uma boa prática ou apenas algo para complicar mais o desenvolvimento.

Ex:

Arquivo config.properties

```
email.user=user
email.host=smtp.email.com
email.auth=true
```

Classe:

```
public class Config {

    private String emailUser;
    private String emailHost;
    private Boolean emailAuth;

    public Config() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
            properties.load(Config.class.getResourceAsStream("/config.properties"));
            emailUser = properties.getProperty("email.user");
            emailHost = properties.getProperty("email.host");
            emailAuth = Boolean.valueOf(properties.getProperty("email.auth"));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //Somente Gets

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em geral me parece uma boa prática para **configurações**, excluindo outros tipos de valores como textos de internacionalização ou listas de valores.

O principal motivo para essa afirmação é porque mais **cedo ou mais tarde você pode decidir mudar a configuração para outra fonte**, como banco de dados, arquivo num caminho específico do disco, um parâmetro no `web.xml` e assim por diante. Nesse caso, você somente precisaria substituir a implementação em um lugar, sem impactar no sistema inteiro.

Outro motivo é **centralizar e padronizar o acesso às as configurações**. Você passa a ter um certo nível de controle de onde e quais configurações está usando. Se cada classe fosse responsável por acessar sua própria configuração, é possível que algum tempo depois fosse difícil rastrear qual configuração é usada em qual lugar.

O último comentário nos leva também ao [**princípio da responsabilidade única**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Cada classe deve ter uma responsabilidade bem definida e única. Código para ficar lendo propriedades no meio de regras de negócio é algo que polui o código.

Porém, como o Vitor bem lembrou, o código pode ficar extenso se houverem muitos *getters*. Outra abordagem é a de um mapa (mais ou menos o que o Rodrigo acabou de mencionar na abordagem do PHP. Só que, embora mais flexível, essa abordagem diminui a rastreabilidade.

Enfim, a decisão cabe a cada projeto. Particularmente, eu nunca trabalhei em projetos com muitos parâmetros onde seria impraticável criar *getters*.

**Atualização sobre a implementação**

Na resposta original, acabei não entrando muito em detalhes de implementação, porém, olhando  mais cuidadosamente o código da pergunta, notei o construtor público.

Isso pode levar a instanciação desnecessária da classe em diversos locais. Você precisa adotar o padrão Singleton e isso pode ser alcançado de duas formas:

1. Método estático. Veja um exemplo de implementação na [Wikipédia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).
2. Injeção de dependências através de um container, tal como Spring, CDI, HK2 EJB.

Answer (score 3):

Se o arquivo for grande essa abordagem vai te dar um certo trabalho.

Pode usar um singleton ou (se estiver usando CDI) algo com escopo de aplicação para abrir o arquivo e manter a instância de Properties.

att

Vitor.

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOPT! Quero louvar o facto de a sua primeira intervenção no site tenho sido através de uma resposta.

Comment: +1 Boas observações.

Answer (score 0):

Eu vou dizer a impressão que tenho ao trabalhar com Symfony que, apesar de ser um framework PHP, é bastante conhecido por forçar que seus desenvolvedores adotem boas práticas (encapsulamento, injeção de dependência, arquitetura voltada a serviços, etc).

As configurações de uma aplicação Symfony em geral vêm de arquivos YAML, apesar de poderem vir também de arquivos XML. O componente de configuração do Symfony, num primeiro momento, valida a sintaxe dos arquivos e joga uma exceção se algo estiver errado.

Daí vem um dos aspectos mais interessantes dele: quando você pega as configurações da aplicação e as *importa* para um bundle, é possível definir um padrão para a configuração daquele bundle – por exemplo:

- O valor não pode ser nulo;
- O valor pode ser nulo, mas se for setado tem que ser um dos valores pré-definidos;
- O valor pode ser um array, um inteiro, um string ou mesmo ter um tipo variável;

Se algum desses valores não se encaixar no padrão definido da configuração, uma exceção é lançada.

Emn seguida, quando as configurações inseridas são validadas, o Symfony compila aquele bundle em um único arquivo PHP, já contendo as configurações (validadas, inclusive) em seu interior. Isso faz com que a aplicação seja carregada muito mais rapidamente e os arquivos de configuração não tenham de ser lidos novamente toda vez que uma requisição for iniciada.

(vale lembrar que o bundle só será compilado se as configurações lá forem válidas, conforme as restrições que você mesmo definiu).

No final das contas, em qualquer ponto da aplicação eu posso buscar a configuração com uma linha de código do tipo:

```
$this->getContainer()->getParameter('endpoint');
```

Enfim, como eu disse, a ideia aqui não é fazer panfletagem de um framework (ok, só um pouquinho), mas expor um conceito de configuração que eu acho muito interessante e que de repente vale a pena ser replicado para outros frameworks. Sendo assim, fica aí uma dica de como você pode implementar tais funcionalidades no seu projeto :)